# Formal proof of “functional” / purposive law

Tags: category-theory

I am really interested in exploring if (legal) laws can be proven to be self-consistent using a formal programming language / proof assistant, and modeling the laws using category theory, perhaps David I. Spivak’s “Categorical Query Language”, or a “process algebra” language like TLA+.

Could anyone please give me a primer on that or refer me to more relevant ideas in research?

(“Purposive law” comes in as the idea that laws could somehow be evaluated as achieving a *purpose*, not a declaration of what is or is not allowed, by what the intended outcome is.)

Thank you very much.

https://dblp.org/pid/59/5301.html

https://iecscience.org/uploads/jpapers/202102/sXyiWTBC21PLv0RLjTbKS3vuHTzTcVttiy1rKHpB.pdf

https://inria.hal.science/hal-03159939/file/paper.pdf

Comment: Possible overlap with https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/nlp-proved-against-us-legal-texts

Comment: I believe https://catala-lang.org/ does what you're asking for to the extent possible...

Comment: @AlexChichigin: you could publish your comment as an answer.

Comment: It could be fascinating to write a political constitution as an ontology log (olog) - a category-theoretic model of human “nature”, “needs”, “rights” or “rules”, logically determined to lack inconsistency. Gödel reportedly said he found an inconsistency in the US Constitution once.

Comment: The title of your question reads like you're asking about a formal proof of some particular law (a theorem) as in "formal proof of the law of excluded middle". I suggest reformulating it.

Answer (score 4):

As a preamble, let me point out that complete (logical) formalization of a legal system is a very long-standing dream. Back in 1987 at the first international conference on Artificial intelligence and law there was a [paper on this topic](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/41735.41757).

We all know such attempts didn't quite land for various reasons. One of the conceptual ones is that no legal system is complete and set in stone: we constantly get new legislations as we go, and resolve holes and clashes in old ones as we discover them. Thus a legal system is always self-contradictory but routinely resolves these contradictions. While we claim that we invented Agile processes, huh? Anyway, most formal logics can't handle contradictions...

That being said, I think the most modern and probably most successful attempt at formalizing and mechanizing (part of) a legal system is [Catala language](https://catala-lang.org).